# TFS Baseless merge, what is the impact?

Tags: tfs

Can anyone tell me succintly (eg point form), what's the impact of a baseless merge in TFS?

Cheers.

Comment: Have you done any independent research on the topic? There are tons of resources out there that explain this.

Comment: yes I have... it seems like you lose the history of commits merged over from the source branch and also auto merges don't work. But the actual code itself is ported across fine with no problems as long as you do the merge conflicts yourself.... unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All a baseless merge does is establish a merge/branch relationship between two items where neither was a branch of the other. After that you can do regular (baseful) merges between the two.